# Config files in package for shared components in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

#### Introduction

I have a huge project which contains many Laravel projects that are responsible for different things. The projects partially share same database (users, permissions, roles, logs...) and for example there is one project which is used to handle user data and permissions for all another projects.

So in this case there was for example duplicated models in the projects (User, Permission, Role). I solved it by building independent package to be included as a Composer package to all projects that share those models.

#### Problem

My question is about required packages' configuration. For example, now I'm using [Spatie's Permission package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to handle permissions and roles. Each of my projects share the same configuration changes in those packages.

- Is there any way to handle those configurations in my shared package, too?
- Can one package override another's config file?
- *How Laravel actually handles that kind of situation that there is configuration files with same name in required packages?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a Shared Service

You can create a package and have all of your projects register it as a 
dependency. Use that package to override all of your dependencies configuration files.

In your shared service you will need to create a service provider for each of the service providers you wish to override. Extend your dependency's service provider and use the `register` method to load your own configuration file rather than that of your dependency's configuration file.

For example:

```
class SharedPermissionServiceProvider extends PermissionServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        if (isNotLumen()) {
            $this->mergeConfigFrom(
                __DIR__.'/../config/permission.php',
                'permission'
            );
        }

        $this->registerBladeExtensions();
    }
}
```

If you are using Laravel 5.5 or higher you may need to [opt-out of package auto-discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#package-discovery) for each of your dependencies in order to prevent your dependencies' service providers from being used. Register your service providers in your `composer.json` instead.

If you are using Laravel 5.4 or lower, or if you are overriding a service provider that does not use auto-discovery, remove your dependencies' service providers from your `config/app.php` and add your own.

Comment: Would this aproach also mean that the `spatie/laravel-permission` is required inside the `composer.json` of the shared package and not the laravel project?

Comment: @bernhardh Yes I believe so. For your package to reference the service you are extending it must be a dependency. Since your project will depend on your shared package, it isn't necessary for it to also have the upstream package as a dependency. I haven't worked on Laravel for a few years now so I apologize if  that's incorrect.

Comment: I tried it out and it works. Not referencing it in the main project means, that you only have to optout of auto-discovery for this in the shared package (so only one time and not in all projects).